# how to protect apps from bypass

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a application which have a refer system

I get user imei no. to as a id of the user

but I checked my application I bypass my application using some app cloner have a funtion to set random imei no.

so how to protect my application from this things

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the IMEI.  First off-  you can't get the IMEI on modern versions of Android.  The OS itself will lie to you unless you're a preinstalled carrier app, the device owner app, or require a permission that normal apps cannot be given.

Secondly-  not all devices have IMEIs.  A tablet without cellular connectivity won't, for example.

Thirdly, its a massive invasion of the user's privacy (and illegal to do in some locations).  Here's google's guidance on what to do for unique ids for your app https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids  Specifically note that you are NOT supposed to use any permanent hardware id as a user id.

Comment: one device one id how to achieve this

Comment: A UUID is sufficient for that.  Just generate a random one.